# Android: FTP client file transfer in passive mode taking time to close connection after 100% upload

Tags: android, asynchronous, ftp

Android: FTP client file transfer in passive mode taking time to close connection after 100% upload

While transferring files through FTP client, in passive mode, we are using async task.
Even after the progress update specified 100% of the file has been uploaded, still ftp connection holds async task from coming to on post execute.

The time taken is directly proportional to Internet speed and size of the file uploaded.

Tried with standalone application to upload zip files,
Tried ftp both in active and passive modes.

Still the issue persists.

```
public class UploadZipFiles extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {
        ArrayList<String> zipFiles;
        String userName, password;
        WeakReference<ServiceStatusListener> listenerReference;
        private Context mContext;
        private long totalFileSize = 0;
        protected long totalTransferedBytes = 0;
        final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        private CustomFtpClient ftpClient = null;

        public UploadZipFiles(Context mContext, ServiceStatusListener listener,
                ArrayList<String> zipFiles, String userName, String password) {
            Log.d("u and p", "" + userName + "=" + password);
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.zipFiles = zipFiles;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
            this.listenerReference = new WeakReference<ServiceStatusListener>(
                    listener);
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // getting total size of the file
            for (String file : zipFiles) {

                totalFileSize = totalFileSize + new File(file).length();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

            ftpClient = new CustomFtpClient();

            try {
                ftpClient.connect(ftpUrl, 21);

                ftpClient.login(userName, password);

                ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                for (String file : zipFiles) {

                    InputStream in;

                    in = new FileInputStream(new File(file));

                    ftpClient.storeFile(new File(file).getName(), in);

                    in.close();

                }


            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "Success";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

            if (result instanceof Exception) {
                listenerReference.get().onFailure(
                        new Exception(result.toString()));
            } else {
                listenerReference.get().onSuccess("Success");
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            int uploadProgress = ((float) values[0] / totalFileSize) * 100);
            //Some code to show loader
            .......


        }

        /** Custom client to publish progress **/

        public class CustomFtpClient extends FTPClient {

            public boolean storeFile(String remote, InputStream local)
                    throws IOException {
                final OutputStream output;
                final Socket socket;

                if ((socket = _openDataConnection_(FTPCommand.STOR, remote)) == null)
                    return false;

                output = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(),
                        getBufferSize());

                try {
                    Util.copyStream(local, output, getBufferSize(),
                            CopyStreamEvent.UNKNOWN_STREAM_SIZE,
                            new CopyStreamListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void bytesTransferred(
                                        long totalBytesTransferred,
                                        int bytesTransferred, long streamSize) {
                                    totalTransferedBytes = totalTransferedBytes
                                            + bytesTransferred;
                                    publishProgress((int) totalTransferedBytes);

                                    if (totalTransferedBytes == totalFileSize) {

                                        Log.d(TAG, "upload completed");

                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void bytesTransferred(
                                        CopyStreamEvent arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException f) {
                    }
                    throw e;                    }
                output.close();
                socket.close();
                return completePendingCommand();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post this in the form of a question and include the code where you are seeing a problem.  It's hard to see what the problem or question is with your current description.

Comment: @mendhak thanks for your quick response. updated question and added comments for code also